# Using one Jquery alert across multplie domains

Tags: jquery, dns, alerts

I need to setup [jNotify](http://www.givainc.com/labs/jnotify_jquery_plugin.htm) or a similar plug-in so it displays an alert, easy enough. My question is how can I do this across multiple domains using only one file.

My goal is to have one jNotify alert file to enable/disable, but being used on 5 websites.

Does anyone have any advise they can share?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you host the jNotify file on one server and use full-path includes on your other websites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include your file with an absolute url

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.yourserver.com/jsfile.js"/>
```

Comment: I didn't think that would work, but what I'm going to do is put the message (alert) in a included file. When I want to disable it, I'll just rename the file.